# Java connect to gremlinserver

Tags: java, gremlin

[**strong text**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOnTj.png)

Trying to connect gremlin server, but problem occured.
Then  I change the GraphMessageSerializerV3d0 to GraphSONMessageSerializerV3d0,but also have some problems.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJY4Y.png)
Can you help me solve the problem? Thank you

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not establish serializer - org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphMessageSerializerV3d0
 at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.Cluster.getBuilderFromSettings(Cluster.java:226)
 at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.Cluster.build(Cluster.java:172)

Comment: This looks similar to your other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71949624/how-can-i-connect-gremlin-driver-initializer. Could you please share the full stack trace and an example of the actual code, not a screen shot?